# What is the filename convention of Makefile templates?

Tags: makefile, filenames

I have a template file, and the configuration script transforms it into the final Makefile. What shoud be the extension of the template?

Example template:

```
EXEC = $var1
PATH = $var2
CC = $var3
STRIP = $var4
MKDIR = $var5
COPY = $var6

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): source.c
    $(CC) $< -o $@
    $(STRIP) $@
    $(MKDIR) $(PATH)
    $(COPY) $@ $(PATH)/
```

The variables are replaced by the configuration script.

Comment: Are you asking for an opinion?  Or do you have a script that requires a template for input?  If the former, use whatever feels right for your use; if the latter, then please provide the script or tell us more about it.

Comment: The second one.
The configuration script creates some makefiles, wich are call each other.

Comment: OK but what is the "configuration script" that you're referring to?  For `automake` for example, you'd use `makefile.am` and add a `configure.ac` and let `automake` do the magic.  See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install.

Comment: This is a custom configuration script written by a late collegue.